# Why some libraries cannot be used in web and command-line apps?

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-io

While reading the article [library tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour) of Dart, I've just discovered that some libraries cannot be used in web apps and other libraries cannot be used or are not available for command-line apps, while all of these mentioned libraries belonging to the standard library.

For example, [`dart:io`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartio---io-for-command-line-apps) cannot be used for web apps, but only for command-line apps. Similarly, only web apps can use [`dart:html`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#darthtml---browser-based-apps), but not command-line ones.

I understood that what `dart:html` offers is more suitable for writing web apps, but I don't understand why there's this restriction of not being able to use some of the services provided by `dart:html` in command-line apps.

Of course, these statements assume that when writing an application in Dart, we have to clearly differentiate between command-line and web apps. Is this true? If yes, are the restrictions above really strict or they are actually recommendations? If they are real restrictions, what was the purpose of designing Dart and its standard library in this way?

Comment: Not sure in what situations you'd need support for files, sockets, environment variables, and HTTP servers within the browser.

Comment: @TobeO HTTP servers _within the browser_?

Comment: Exactly my point - that's why dart:io is server-side only. Its features aren't supported by browsers

Comment: @TobeO Are all the services provided by `dart:io` not supported by browsers or not going to be supported? I'm still wondering if using or not `dart:io`, for example, on the client-side of a web app is impossible or possible but not recommended.

Comment: It's impossible to use dart:io in the browser, but you can use it in the VM or in Flutter

Comment: @TobeO What do you mean exactly by impossible? Does the Dart to JS transpiler give us an error if we try to use `dart:io` in a client-side app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152896/discussion-between-nbro-and-tobe-o).

Comment: Yes, it'll give an error. Similarly, you can't use dart:html on the server.

Answer (score 3):

`dart:html` talks to a DOM.  There is no DOM in a VM.  Similarly, `dart:io` talks to the operating system in a manner that a browser cannot.  (Your browser cannot launch processes, open files, or set up sockets other than AJAX and WebSockets.) The separation makes sense.